# chdir in php can't work

Tags: php, chdir

I want to change directory using `chdir` in php, because i need to execute command in Linux.
My current directory is `/var/www/httpdocs/website/admin`,I want to go to httpdocs's sub_directory `docs`.I use absolute path like:

```
chdir("/var/www/httpdocs/docs");
```

but it does't work.

I only can get website using : `chdir("../");`
or get admin's sub_directory `images` using : `chdir("/var/www/httpdocs/website/admin/images");`

but I can't get `httpdocs`.
what's wrong?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have enough user rights to go outside of the `website` directory ?

If you enable error display, maybe you will understand what's going on. Please try your script again by adding this on top of your php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

And let me know which error messages you see.

Comment: This should have been a comment instead.

Comment: I did as what you said.But no error to give back.will it give errors when chdir() return false?

Comment: If you do `print_r(chdir("/var/www/httpdocs/docs"));` what can you see ?

Comment: I try it and see nothing on web page.If I do if(chdir("/var/www/httpdocs/docs")) echo "a";else echo "b";Then I can see b on web page.

Comment: Are you sure that he path `/var/www/httpdocs/docs` is correct ? If it is, the only reason for this chdir to fail is due to a access forbidden. It can be due to a php safe_mode or your server configuration. Maybe try to change the chmod on the docs directory.

Comment: Thank you very much.You are right.It really because of access forbidden.